# What training approach should I have to miss gym for 2 months?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, gym, olympic-weightlifting, you-are-your-own-gym

So I have to go out of the city for 2 months to my hometown.Now I do have a gym there but it's a very small and simple gym,they do have basic equipment but the weights are not much heavy.For ex.I need 25kg DB for lunges but the gym only has 12.5kg.On the other hand,in case of core lifts like squats,bench and DL,I will have problems in squats and DL coz I do 4*3 sets of 100 kg but plates are up to 80 kg only, besides in bench I won't having anyone to spot me.
So in this scenario what should be my approach to training,I don't want to lose my strength/muscle gains and the sessions also should be challenging enough.
1.I usually do a heavy training approach for straight gains, should I switch to a more rep range style?
2.Should I incorporate explosive movements and if I do,what type?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you will not have access to heavier weights, I think you will likely have to increase your rep range. Another thing that you can do is look for exercise modifications that will increase the difficulty of the exercise, which may allow you to use the weights available for you. For example, you could try replacing the DB Lunge with a DB Elevated Split Squat. Put one foot on a bench or a box and perform a split squat. For deadlift, you could try doing a single leg deadlift, which will also work your core and test your balance.

2) I love explosive movements and I try to do at least one set of explosive movements in every workout. It could be as simple as starting your workout with box jumps. Do three sets at five reps and see how that feels.

Overall, I feel like as long as your training, when you return to your normal routine in two months, you will be able to get back to your normal performance much more quickly than if you weren't training at all.

Answer (score 1):

High rep hypertrophy work will not only retain muscle, but will also condition your musculature to get ready for heavy lifting after the break. Lifting in only low rep ranges is suboptimal, especially since you are a beginner. Every good strength training program has a hypertrophy phase in the beginning.

In fact, I believe this is an excellent opportunity to do improve lagging areas, stuff that people are usually lazy about - like mobility, posture, cardiovascular efficiency. This will complement your ability to move heavy weight and stay injury-free.

You can also try stuff that challenges you in new ways - unilateral exercises, bodyweight exercises, calisthenic movements, squat/bench/deadlift variations.

Some links:

- Mobility/bodyweight/calisthenics - https://antranik.org/fitness-index
- Posture - this article series https://www.t-nation.com/training/neanderthal-no-more-1
- Common weaknesses - https://exrx.net/Kinesiology/Weaknesses